# Accessing a container from another container using the public IP of the host

Tags: networking, iptables, proxmox, containers

I've some issues configuring properly the network in proxmox.

In short, from a container, I can reach any web server outside (ex: google.com), but I can't reach the web server on my container. The web server is reachable from internet.

## Here is the setup :

DNS : mydomain.example -> x.x.x.x/32

## Host

vmbr0: x.x.x.x
 venet0: (routing to each container)

Iptables rules :

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d x.x.x.x --dport 80 -i vmbr0 -j DNAT --to-destination y.y.y.z:n
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o vmbr0 -s y.y.y.0/24 ! -d y.y.y.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
```

## Containers

venet0: y.y.y.z

## Issues

Commands executed from a container :

ping google.com : **OK**
ping mydomain.example : **OK**
wget http://google.com **OK**
wget http://mydomain.example : **KO**

```
Resolving mydomain.example... x.x.x.x
Connecting to mydomain.example|x.x.x.x|:80... failed: Connection refused.
```

What I'm missing ? Do you need more info ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the `-i` option in your `prerouting` rule.

Here, requests are coming from `venet0` interface, so your actual `DNAT` rule does not apply.